# Is there a mac os x version of lsdev?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix

As listed in the title,

Is there an alternative for 
lsdev

on mac os bash?

Comment: You might start with providing some information about what `lsdev` is.

Comment: In particular, what information from `lsdev` do you need from an OSX equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely different format and some common, some different information, but this may help:

```
system_profiler
```

Credit to https://serverfault.com/a/8647

Note `lsdev` interrogates the `/proc/` filesystem interface into the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) kernel.  This interface does not exist in OSX, so a direct `lsdev` port would be highly non-trivial.